# Display scaled contents

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page where the content is a printable canvas. I need the page/canvas to have a width: 21cm and a height: 29.7cm while displaying a scaled version of that canvas and anything on it in a UI.

This is what i tried but it broke any third party tools that crossed it and ruins the layout.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .display-board {
            width: 21cm;
            height: 29.7cm;
            zoom: 0.5;
            -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
        }  
    </style>
</head>
    <body>
        <section></section>
        <section class="canvas">
            <canvas class="display-board"></canvas>    <!-- The drawing canvas -->
        </section>
        <section></section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your css is lacking semi-colons.

Comment: @retterBadach thanks I've been using SASS a lot.